# Restoring database: FROM DISK = variable + string -> Incorrect syntax near '+'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My purpose is to have script that restores database from backup file.

```
USE [master]

DECLARE @backupsFolder NVARCHAR(256) = N'C:\DatabaseBackups\'

RESTORE DATABASE [MY_DB] FROM  DISK = @backupsFolder + 'MY_DB.bak'enter code here
```

While executing there is an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Issue is just when path is concatenated. Only variable or only string work OK.
I tried also wrap this with brackets -> still doesn't work.
It is not a big deal for me to add variable like this:

```
DECLARE @bakPath NVARCHAR(256) = @backupsFolder + 'MY_DB.bak'
```

Just interesting why SQL Server doesn't allow me to concatenate value right after DISK = ?

Comment: No procedure allows you to build the input parameter as part of calling it. Its just the way SQL Server works.

Comment: T-SQL is an old and crusty language. One thing you have to learn is that it's not *orthogonal* in a lot of places. You may be used to languages where you can substitute *expressions* freely in locations where a *constant or variable* may be used. Well, T-SQL isn't one of those.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use dynamic SQL to do this. This should be enough to get you started:

```
DECLARE @backupsFolder NVARCHAR(256) = N'C:\DatabaseBackups\'
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'RESTORE DATABASE [MY_DB] FROM  DISK = ' + REPLACE(@backupsFolder,N'''',N'''''') + 'MY_DB.bak --enter code here';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Note I would *normally* use `QUOTENAME` instead of `REPLACE` to minimise injection, however, file paths can (and do) have more than 128 characters.